# Statistical significance of parameters in nonlinear model

Tags: statistical-significance, matlab, curve-fitting

I have historical data for mineral production in a specified region, from 1972 to 2014. I fitted the data to a model following a bell shape, in order to estimate the peak year and production. The model I used for calculating prodution at year *t* has the form:

[image: bell shaped formula used]

where *P_pk* is the peak production, *T_pk* is the peak year, *k* and *b* are constants that determine the curve slope. I used the Matlab function *fminsearch* to find the *P_pk* and *T_pk* that minimize the RMS error between the real values and the modeled curve.

After presenting the work for revision, I have been said that statistical significance of the fitted parameters should be reported.

I have no experience with methods used for parameter statistical significance of nonlinear models, could yo please help me with some advice of the approach that could be used or where can I find some information that could guide me?

Comment: I suggest adding the "matlab" tag to the question.

Comment: Do you have access to R?

Comment: Yes, I do. Although no too much experience working with it